# Point Cloud Library and While Loop

Tags: pointers, while-loop, save, point-cloud-library

i am new to C++ and PCL. i wish to save the values of pointer in while loop and wanted to display the saved one . Here is part of my code . Please guide how to save the value of "coefficients->values[0] ,coefficients->values[1], coefficients->values[2], coefficients->values[3]" in an array each time loop runs.

```
// While 20% of the original cloud is still there
  while (cloud_filtered->points.size () > 0.20 * nr_points)
  {
    // Segment the largest planar component from the remaining cloud
    seg.setInputCloud (cloud_filtered);
    seg.segment (*inliers, *coefficients);

    if (inliers->indices.size () == 0)
        {
        std::cerr << "Could not estimate a planar model for the given dataset." << std::endl;
        break;
        }
    std::cerr << "Model coefficients: " << coefficients->values[0] << " " 
                                        << coefficients->values[1] << " "
                                        << coefficients->values[2] << " "                                   
                                        << coefficients->values[3] << std::endl;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are following [this](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/planar_segmentation.php) example code since the snippet you added in your question is almost to same. If this is the case, then you can declare a `std::vector<pcl::ModelCoefficients>` just before the while loop and push the coefficients into that like

```
std::vector<pcl::ModelCoefficients> coeffs;
while(...){
    ...
    coeffs.push_back(*coefficients);
}
```

Also check the documentation for `pcl::ModelCoefficients` [here](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.1/structpcl_1_1_model_coefficients.html) which is nothing but a header and a vector of floats. Note that defining the `coeffs` as a vector of shared pointers and pushing pointers to the coefficients will not work in this case since previously pushed coefficients will be overwritten by `seg.segment(*inliers, *coefficients);`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response .

My issue is i want all coefficients , as you said "previously pushed coefficients will be overwritten " . Is there any way i can save all the coefficients in some variable

Comment: What he wrote does does not overwrite as he defined the vector with modelcoefficients objects rather than shared pointers.  He is explaining why the pointer "coefficients" from your code snippet needs to be dereferenced "*" inside the push_back in order to not overwrite past entries.